# How to add shortcut keys for java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Say I type "sout", the intellisense should expand it to "System.out.println()". Is there a way to adding such templates?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The feature is called "code templates" in Eclipse.  You can add templates with:

> Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates.

Two good articles:

- [Don't write the code, generate it](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-dont-write-c)
- [Custom Templates](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ)

Also, this SO question:

- [Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates)

`System.out.println()` is already mapped to `sysout`, so you may save time by learning a few of the existing templates first.

Answer (score 29):

Type "`Sysout`" and then `Ctrl+Space`. It expands to

```
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 14):

Type `syso` and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 7):

type "syso" and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>space</kbd>

OR

type "sysout" and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>space</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

This is one more option: go to Windows > Preference > Java > Editor > Content Assit. Look in "Auto Activation" zone, sure that "Enable auto activation" is checked and add more charactor (like "abcd....yz, default is ".") to auto show content assist menu as your typing.

Answer (score 1):

I've been Eclipse-free for over a year now, but I believe Eclipse calls these "Templates". Look in your settings for them. You invoke a template by typing its abbreviation and pressing the normal code completion hotkey (ctrl+space by default) or using the Tab key. The standard eclipse shortcut for System.out.println() is "sysout", so "sysout" would do what you want.

Here's another stackoverflow question that has some more details about it:
[How to use the "sysout" snippet in Eclipse with selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020027/how-to-use-the-sysout-snippet-in-eclipse-with-selected-text)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 -> Top apple icon -> System preference -> keyboard -> Shortcut>spotlight -> uncheck.
Step 2 ->Eclipse -> General -> keys -> search -> content Assist ->
Binding (cmd button + space) -> Apply&close.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30616785)