# netbeans like typing shortcut code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

netbeans like typing shortcut code in eclipse
e.g. psvm press tab get public static void main
 sout is for `System.out.println();`

https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf please refer page 2.

This kind of shortcuts I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

type `sysout` and then press `ctrl +space`

Comment: code templates are expanded using the `tab` key. `ctrl-space` is for Java syntax completion

Comment: I'm sorry sir but didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

These kind of shortcuts are called **Code Templates** in eclipse (and also in Netbeans by the looks of the pdf that you refer in your question).
Here are the common ones

"sysout" + ctrl + space --> `System.out.println()`
"syserr" + ctrl + space --> `System.err.println()`
"systrace" + ctrl + space ---> `System.out.println("OwnerClass.CurrentMethod()")`  ... bascially prints the current method to standard out.

If you forget them at any time just type `sys` and hit ctrl+space, and you will get these in the auto-complete menu like this:
[image]

Also checkout this awesome SO question addressing this question for **other common code templates** (other than `System.out.println()`): [Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates)

**Create your own shortcuts**: [How to add shortcut keys for java code in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659042/how-to-add-shortcut-keys-for-java-code-in-eclipse); [Effective Eclipse: Don't write the code, generate it](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-dont-write-c)

[**Other eclipse shortcuts**](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html)

Comment: https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf please refer page 2. This kind of shorcuts I am looking for.

Comment: page two's heading is "Highlights of NetBeans IDE 7.0 Keyboard Shortcuts & Code Templates" ... which, I think, is exactly what i am talking about in my answer. I detail how to use standard code templates and resources on how to create your own. The last link in my answer provides 93 general purpose keyboard shortcuts (not code templates). If there is something you are looking for specifically, kindly say so.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned short cut for `System.out.println()` is to type `sysout` and press ctrl+space bar.

But there are other helpful shortcuts in eclipse which you can use. You cna check them by going to eclipse-> Click help -> Key Assist.