# "syso" shortcut in Eclipse- changing a bit behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I look for some trick which gives me possibility to change the syso behaviour in Eclipse (please assume that below there is Eclipse´s editor), now it works in this way:

syso%someVariable

% - means the plase when i typed ctrl + space, and result is:

```
System.out.println();someVariable
```

but I want to have of course without copying text..:

```
System.out.println(someVariable);
```

Any hints ? :-) Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't think, but the similar thing would be like this `System.out.println(${var})`

Comment: You have to write your own template for sysout and add it to the eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659042/how-to-add-shortcut-keys-for-java-code-in-eclipse)

The feature is called "code templates" in Eclipse.  You can add templates with Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates.  Two good articles:

- http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-dont-write-c
- http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ

Also, this SO question:

- [Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates)

`System.out.println()` is already mapped to `sysout`, so you may save time by learning a few of the existing templates first.

Answer (score 2):

If you wan´t to change current template you can press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>end</kbd> (to select 'someVariable') and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd> to select sysout.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the original question or at least how I understood it:

Modify the existing template syntax for sysout (Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates find sysout and select edit) to read:

```
System.out.println(${cursor});
```

Now you can type syso and then ctr+space and instantly get the output:

```
System.out.println(<cursorHere>);
```

Or as you put it:

```
System.out.println(someVariable);
```

...with the cursor inside the brackets which is indeed more efficient than starting after the semicolon.