# How to edit syso or add a custom System.out.println(); in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

So I mainly use a Mac with Eclipse and I know there is a shortcut to type `System.out.println();` using syso CTRL+Space, but I was wondering if there is any way where I can change or add my own shortcut by just typing something like `sysout` and not have to press CTRL+Space, but instead just by pressing Space after `sysout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Preferences > General > Editor > Keys

- In column "Command" Search for "Content Assist", select it
- Below in "Binding" erase the content (ctrl+space), and just press space
- PRESS OK
- DONE

[See the image, it is easy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yd0x.png)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is already supported. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659088/3166303). `sysout` is the the template and you can just hit `tab` to complete it. No need for `CRTL+space`. If it's really important to you to use `space` rather than `tab`, you would need to update the key bindings under `Preferences > General > Editor > Keys`, but it may interfere with other key bindings so I wouldn't suggest you change that.