# How can I change the post fix template in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

So there is this new feature which will allow post fixes.
Example is that if I have `String s = "hello";` then I can type `s.sysout` and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>  and it will change to `System.out.println(s);`
In the Eclipse Template proposals, this is what it has `System.out.println(${i:inner_expression(java.lang.String)}${});${cursor}` in the description. So basically it works for any String
How can I edit that line so it will work for anything? ie int, double, boolean, anything (it would take that and put it in a `System.out.println()`  )

Edit: it is not a duplicate, I want to edit the above code in the template so it would work for every data type not just Strings. Right now, there was only 1 answer so I accepted it

Comment: You might find your answers here: https://github.com/trylimits/Eclipse-Postfix-Code-Completion This can be useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020027/how-to-use-the-sysout-snippet-in-eclipse-with-selected-text

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, because you accepted an answer linking to that question. If it is not a duplicate, then [edit] your question to clarify why it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I just edited how do i open the question again